# Lie algebra 3 Dimensional with 2 Dimensional derived lie algebra #2

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I read the book of Karin Erdmann and Mark Wildon: "An introduction to Lie algebras". In page 22 they say that:

> If $\dim (L) = 3$, $\dim (L') = 2$ then (a) $L'$ abelian and (b) $\operatorname{ad} x : L' \rightarrow L'$ is an isomorphism

I have problem now to prove part (b) of lemma 3. $\operatorname{ad} x : L' \rightarrow L'$. I stuck to show $\operatorname{ad} x : L' \rightarrow L$ is a homomorphism. How to show that $\operatorname{ad} x([y,z]) = [\operatorname{ad} x(y), \operatorname{ad}x(z)]$ where $y,z \in L'$.

Thanks for your kindness

Comment: Hint: You have already shown that $L'$ is abelian, so the bracket $[y,z]$ equals what?

Comment: ah i see, i really cant see it, thanks, yea
Omg i'm so sorry to bother u guys with this silly question

Comment: @Tobias: You should convert it into an answer, so that the OP can mark as answered.

Comment: @OngokOngoksepen I told you already the book has two authors.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer : yeah, i'm a bit confuse learn chapter three in that book, for me it's not easy to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first part showed that $L'$ is abelian, we have $\rm{ad}_x([y,z]) = \rm{ad}_x(0) = 0$ and on the other hand, we have that both $\rm{ad}_x(y) = [x,y]$ and $\rm{ad}_x(z) = [x,z]$ are elements of $L'$, so the bracket $[\rm{ad}_x(y),\rm{ad}_x(z)] = 0$, and hence the map is a homomorphism.

Comment: solve, thanks sir